# Why do check_nrpe not work in remote server?

Tags: nagios, nrpe

I installed Nagios to my local server, and am monitoring a CentOS server.
All the plugins (nagios plugins and nrpe) are installed too, and working in local, but not via my server. Generic services are monitored well but others (local services) aren't working. Statut information shows: `CHECK_NRPE STATE CRITICAL: Socket timeout after 30 seconds`.

I've installed nrpe in my remote host and added commands in nrpe.cfg.
In my nagios server, I defined those commands in my server's configuration file.

When I check those commands in my centOS server, it works well.
For exemple when I type:

```
./check_procs -w 250 -c 300
```

prompt shows:

```
PROCS AVERTISSEMENT: 284 processus | procs=284;250;300;0;
```

Or the command: `./check_nrpe -H localhost`
It shows: `NRPE v3.2.1`

Everything seems working, but if I try: `./check_nrpe -H monitoredserver`, it doesn't work.

Also, in nagios web interface, every local service in monitored server shows: `CHECK_NRPE STATE CRITICAL: Socket timeout after 30 seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify common mistakes which you can have:

1. Your NRPE daemon is not started on remote server

   Run `service nrpe status` on remote server and verify NRPE state.
2. Test your network connection

   Run `telnet monitoredserver 5666` from Nagios server and test your connection. If this command fail, then you have firewall between these servers.

Comment: Re 1: There's no problem detected

Comment: Re 2: When I run telnet monitored server 5666, it shows me: "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out"

Comment: So you have setup firewall which blocking your traffic to port 5666. Can you `ping monitoredserver` without problem?

Comment: Yes, there's no problem with ping

Comment: Try run this command on `monitoredserver` as root: `netstat -natup|grep nrpe`. Can you share result with us?

Comment: Done. Result: [root@client-monitoredserver ~]# netstat -natup | grep nrpe
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2962/nrpe           
tcp6       0      0 :::5666                 :::*                    LISTEN      2962/nrpe

Comment: Okey, so you have definitely firewall between `monitoredserver` and Nagios server. You should edit your firewall rules and allow remote connection to port 5666/tcp.

Comment: Ok thanks, it was a firewall problem. I solved it and everything is ok. Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: Please how did you solve the firewall problem, I have same issue